# Element attributes in headless chrome not the same as regular chrome so selenium returns NoSuchElementException

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

This code works in regular chrome:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep


def login(email, password):

    with webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver') as driver:

        driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup?ssrc=head&returnurl=%2fusers%2fstory%2fcurrent%27')
        sleep(2)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="openid-buttons"]/button[1]').click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="email"]').send_keys(email)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]').click()
        sleep(3)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="password"]').send_keys(password)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]').click()
        sleep(2)
        driver.get('https://youtube.com')


login('email', 'password')
```

However, in headless chrome, selenium keeps returning NoSuchElementException for different elements.

I have verified that almost all attributes are different by getting the page HTML of headless chrome, but even without that you can see the different Google login pages regular and headless chrome access:

[image: Regular chrome]
[image: Headless chrome]

I don’t think it’s because regular chrome is in my language. Element attributes are entirely different, not just the text labels.

Why is this the case and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

this means that the elements are randomized, try looking it up again on your normal browser and see if it changed from previously, if it did then its impossible to capture it by using XPath, you would have to use class name or cssSelector! good luck

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. Class names are also changed. It seems like all elements are different. It's a completely different page.